# Pourrait-on remplacer "d'à côté" par "à côté" ?

Tags: sens

Bonjour,

Dans *Le Pont de Londres* de L.-F. Céline :

> Je ramponne dans le peloton d'à côté ! Je défonce une muraille....

Pourrait-on remplacer *d'à côté* par *à côté* ici ?

Est-ce seulement à cause de la musicalité et pour jouer sur les allitérations que l'auteur a choisi d'écrire *d'à côté* ?

Comment: Non, "à côté" est une expression toute faite.  L'article **de (d')** explique une appartenance. Ce n'est pas le peloton de l'avant-garde, par exemple.

Comment: @Lambie Please don't write answers in comments. Doing so bypasses our community-moderated quality measures by not permitting community editing or paired up- and down-voting available on comments. Comments are for clarifying and improving the question; please don't use them for other purposes.

Answer (score 1):

La réponse suivante n'est pas une explication nette et claire mais un ensemble de résultats qui ne sont que le préliminaire d'une recherche qui offrirait des résultats plus concluants. Je la propose quand même pour ce qu'elle peut susciter d'idées nouvelles sur ce problème.

Il existe une différence qui n'est pas toujours bien exploitée à mon avis.

« À côté » joue le rôle d'une proforme dans certains contextes et devient un moyen de référence à une place bien définie.

*Exemple typique : la maison des voisins, la maison voisine* (dans cet usage, « à côté » semble être de registre familier.)

- Ils n'ont plus d'électricité **à côté**. (*les voisins dans la  maison adjacente …*)
- Je suis allé **à côté** et on m'a dit que le chat n'était pas  à eux. (*…allé chez les voisins…*)
- Il parait qu'**à côté** il y a une nouvelle famille ; je me demande pourquoi ils sont  partis sans rien dire. (*dans la maison à côté …*)

Dans ces cas-là « à côté » se construit assez naturellement en tant que complément de nom.

Par exemple, lorsqu'on dit « **les gens d'à côté** », ce qui signifie « les gens qui habitent dans la maison adjacente à celle de la personne qui parle », il s'agit d'une construction qui représente une relation réelle d'appartenance à une place. On ne dit pas alors aussi aisément « les gens à côté », mais voilà un exemple.

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Les_Veilleurs/1Ocriiky1JsC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22les+gens+%C3%A0+c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%22&pg=PT234&printsec=frontcover))   saison – les enfants avaient abandonné ce pays. Les gens à côté s'inquiétaient. 15 décembre. Pas de neige. C'est sûr que ceux qui ont misé là-dessus i vont être obligés de…

Si on prend maintenant le cas d'une personne qui parle d'une suite de maisons dans une rue où elle n'habite pas et qu'après avoir donné quelques informations sur une maison elle veut parler de la maison suivante, alors elle ne dira pas « la maison d'à côté », mais au lieu de cela, elle dira « la maison à côté » parce qu'il n'est pas nécessaire de passer par l'intermédiaire d'une place définie comme étant « à côté ».

« À côté » ne devrait pas être remplacé par « d'à côté » lorsqu'il n'existe qu'une notion de proximité.

- Elle avait demandé au premier enfant dans la file mais c'est l'enfant à côté qui répondit.

Autre concept qui se prête à cet usage, le mot « salle » ne semble pas justifier « salle d'à côté » que l'on trouve pourtant souvent ; c'est à dire qu'il est tout aussi correct de dire « salle à côté ».

[réf. 1](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Danse_de_mort/ECD9o2kfnIwC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22la+salle+d%27%C3%A0+c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%22&pg=PT165&printsec=frontcover), [réf. 2](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Mus%C3%A9e_des_familles/dpU9AAAAYAAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22la+salle+d%27%C3%A0+c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%22&pg=PA10&printsec=frontcover), [réf. 3](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/La_Dame_d_Ol%C3%A9ron/1wcuEAAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22la+salle+d%27%C3%A0+c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%22&pg=PT101&printsec=frontcover), [réf. 4](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/18_3_Une_ann%C3%A9e_%C3%A0_la_PJ/nJbHDwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22la+salle+d%27%C3%A0+c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%22&pg=PT28&printsec=frontcover), [réf.5](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Le_clan_des_Winston_l_int%C3%A9grale/wkKhCwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22la+salle+d%27%C3%A0+c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%22&pg=PT152&printsec=frontcover), …

I existe d'autres noms (village d'à côté, usine d'à côté, …) pour lesquels « de » pourrait être suppimé sans changer le sens.

([réf.](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Soleil_gasoil/5bMSCwAAQBAJ?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22village+%C3%A0+c%C3%B4t%C3%A9%22&pg=PT196&printsec=frontcover)) Elle — elle est du village à côté et elle attend le bus devant l'abri en métal rouille rouille et dans le vent

Il pourrait être le cas que « à côté » soit perçu comme n'étant pas assez précis.

Dans le cas de la phrase de Céline, il n'est pas clair qu'une correspondance justifiant l'emploi de « à côté » en tant que proforme existe. « Je défonce une muraille » : c'est apparemment une muraille symbolique, celle que forment les combattants sur le côté du peloton.

Il y a dans son livre un second exemple de cet usage, qui semble pertinent.

- Bram ! Bra ! les volets qui sonnent... Encore les polices ! Heureux
  c'était pas les vrais !... c'était seulement les « vigiles », ceux d'à côté, du
  dock Poplar... (Noter que « les polices » est un anglicisme toujours pas admis)

Au lieu du cas typique de voisinage de maison, il s'agit d'un voisinage de docks et la forme « d'à côté » convient, mais le véritable argument que l'on pourrait peut-être faire serait  que traiter « à côté » en tant que proforme supprimerait l'effet vague qu'un simple « à côté » communiquerait.

Comment: LPH, franchement, je pense que c'est largement suffisant pour "à côté*. Par contre, le contraste pour lee mot peloton (de devant, d'arrière [par exemple]) ne rentrait guère dans ton analyze....:)

Comment: @Lambie Je ne comprends pas ce que vous essayez d'expliquer, vous pouvez préciser ?

Comment: Bien sûr. Le d' ou de renvoi à un lieu dans l'espace. Cad, ce n'est pas le peloton d'en face.  Voilà de genre de contraste en jeu. Si on enlève le d', cela change le sens complètement....Il y un syntagme ici ou le "de" signale une appartenance ou un positionnement/

Comment: @Lambie Ce n'est pas le point de vue qui me semble approprié.  Que ce soit un peloton entier ou un simple soldat, il n'y a pas de différence ; pour un simple soldat on dit très bien «  le soldat à côté » et de plus « le soldat d'à côté » semble ne pas convenir parce qu'il n'y a rien de spécial en ce qui concerne cet emplacement (du point de vue des conventions). On ne dira pas dans le contexte de cet emplacement « J'ai frappé à côté », mais dans le contexte de voisins on dira « j'ai frappé à côté » (pour dire « j'ai frappé à la porte des voisins ». Il y a une différence importante.

Comment: le soldat à côté ne veut pas dire: le soldat d'à côté, pourquoi? A cause du d'. Ici, c'est pareil.

Comment: @Lambie Qu'est-ce qui est dit d'autre dans « soldat d'à côté » ? Il y a des quantités de « village d'à côté » et autre exemples de cette sorte qui ne disent pas autre chose que « village à côté ».

Comment: La maison à côté DE quelque chose, ce qui donne: la maison d'à côté. Sauf qu'ici pour le peloton, on n'a pas le contexte. Voilà.

Comment: @Lambie D'accord sur ce point, le contexte est incertain.